# new() keyword at the end of method declaration

Tags: c#, syntax, new-operator, keyword, method-declaration

A workmate just gave me some C# classes that I must use in a .NET application.
There's a typo that I have never seen, and I can't found any explication on the internet...

Here's the code :

```
public void GoTo<TView>() where TView : Form, new()
{
    var view = Activator.CreateInstance<TView>();

    //si on vient de creer une startup view alors on affiche l'ancienne
    //la reference a la nouvelle sera detruite en sortant de la fonction GoTo
    if (view is StartupForm)
    {
        ShowView(_StartupForm);
    }
    else ShowView(view);

}
```

What is the `new()` keyword for, right at the end of the method declaration ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx):

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class
>   declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the
>   new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

So when you say:

```
void myMethod<T>(T item) where T : class, new();
```

then it means that you are putting a constraint on generic parameter T. So T should be a reference type and cannot be a value type(*int, float, double etc*). Also T should have a public parameter-less default constructor.

Answer (score 11):

It is [type parameter constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). Literally it means `TView` must have a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: As an addition to this  answer you can use following in your code: var variable = new TView(); while without new() constraint its not allowed by C# compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is a type parameter constraint, specifically a *constuctor-constraint*, detailed in Section 10.1.5 of the C# Language Specification.

> If the where clause for a type parameter includes a constructor constraint (which has the form new() ), it is
>   possible to use the new operator to create instances of the type (§7.6.10.1). Any type argument used for a type
>   parameter with a constructor constraint must have a public parameterless constructor (this constructor implicitly
>   exists for any value type) or be a type parameter having the value type constraint or constructor constraint (see
>   §10.1.5 for details).

This is just a way of guaranteeing that the type passed in can be constructed with a parameterless constructor.